# Positioning navigation inside a full width fixed header

Tags: css, header, positioning, nav

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- A responsive site
- A full width, fixed header that holds 2 elements:
- A logo positioned at the far left,
- and the main navigation bar.

There is an h1 that is actually outside the header tag and in the body, it shows in the header because the header is semi-transparent.

This is the site. [Subject site](http://www.allaccessbranding.com/)

The problem is:
On my screen the nav is positioned where I want it. Which is to say: the last link is lined up with the right edge of the centered content area.

However, when the browser window is re-sized the nav (expectedly) moves to the left and eventually breaks off when it encounters the logo.

What I want to do is have the nav stay positioned over the right side of the main content until it reaches a break point, where I will use a css media query to fix it from there.

Many thanks in advance!

Here is the html:
(I have tried many combinations of AP, floats, margins (%, px,) etc..)

```
<h1 class="header_text">Welcome...</h1>
<header>
<a href="http://www.allaccessbranding.com">
<img id="logo" src="./images/aai_logo_black_108x211.gif" alt="All Access International logo" />
</a>
<div id="main_nav">
<nav id="main_nav_tag">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" 
        id="here">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" 
        >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" 
        >Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.php" 
        >Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php" 
        >Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" 
        >Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
body {
    min-width: 960px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 108px;
    z-index: 100; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(99,0,0);
}
header #logo {
    float: left;    
}
.header_text {
    margin: 35px 0px 0px 23%;
    font-family: 'Aguafina Script', cursive;
    font-size: 4.6em;
    color: #279D9D;
}
#main_nav {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 19%;
    margin-top: 56px;
}
#main_nav_tag {
    margin: 15px 0 0 5px;
}
#main_nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;    
    width: auto;
}
#main_nav ul li a {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}
#main_nav ul li a:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(99,0,0);
}
#main_nav ul li #here {
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(99,0,0);
}
```

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ for make simlpe fiddle

Comment: If you add mockup images of how you want the site to look (before and after the media queries) then I will fix it all. I ask for images as I am finding it hard to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure it out. I simply positioned the logo absolute, taking it out of flow. 
I gave the nav container a width of 960px (matching the content area), and applied margin: 0 auto to it, which kept the nav container centered on the page. I then applied float: right to the nested nav tag which brought it to the right edge of the container and violla! The nav stays in position on re-size. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have `float: left` in your `#main_nav ul li`, this is problem.

Change `#main_nav ul li` float to right, like this:

```
#main_nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;    
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M_Abooali/JKQkQ/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately not the right one. The nav still moves left as the browser is re-sized.

Comment: I have added the code to the remote server so you can see yourself.

Comment: I also added an image on the index page so you have a better point of reference. I am waiting on permission to use this image so I had it offsite.

Comment: Not having heard of fiddle before I did not understand the reference at first. I am on there now trying to figure out how it works, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the advice, but fiddle was no help and the issue remains. But, thanks again.

Comment: I'm not understand what do you want really, we talk about header menu, that's right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to keep the header menu above the right side of the centered content area even when the browser window is re-sized or if the user is viewing on a smaller screen. You can see that if you re-size the browser, the menu starts to shift left and is no longer 'lined-up' with the right edge of the main content area.